# Jumbo Packet in 1 Gigabit Ethernet- help

Tags: ethernet

I would like to know about Jumbo Packets using UDP in 1 Giga etherent.

What are the delays in such system?

i think of using jumbo packets in my system because i need to transfer a lot of data between 2 computers.

i tried to find information about the delays and what are the disadvantages using jumbo packets in 1 gigabit- i didn't find a lot.
(I find many advantages but i would like to know also the disadvantages)

Thank you very much for the help,

Answer (score 2):

The largest problem that you can actually run into is the hardware not supporting the jumbo frames. Keep in mind that, if you have a large network, switches or routers which don't support jumbo frames will drop them, since the standard Ethernet frame size is 1518 octets - hardware that's not aware of jumbo frames will assume that what follows after that number of octets is the CRC of the data, and drop the frame after getting a mismatch.

Also, it is said that larger frames may hurt multimedia applications which require short response times. This seems rather weird to me, because setting the maximum MTU to something larger than the standard doesn't change the minimum frame size on an interface, so small frames can still be safely sent out.